# Redux thunk - Error · Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions even with dispatch an object with key type

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-actions

Getting below error for specific action functions:

> Error · Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async
> actions

Below code works fine on my system but loging erros on [bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/) for different users.

React component file:

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';

 const dispatch = useDispatch();
 const handleTabs = tab => {
    dispatch(resetActionType());
    tabChanged(tab);
  };
```

Action file:

```
export function resetActionType() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'RESET_ACTION_TYPE',
    });
  };
}
```

Checking different questions on SO I could understand this error comes when we don't use dispatch or type key in object returned in dispatch.
But I am doing both of them.

Error is not happening on all machines/OS/browsers.
Coming for a few users only.

What is wrong with the above code? Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is not happening for every action, so I guess configuration is fine.

**UPDATE:**

I am using redux thunk.

Answer (score 0):

```
export function resetActionType() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'RESET_ACTION_TYPE',
    });
  };
}
```

this syntax is used if you setup redux-thunk middleware. the purpose of redux-thunk to make the async request and once the request is resolved, it dispatches the response data. that is why `dispatch` is passed an argument. since you have no async code inside action creator, you must return a plain object.

When you connect to the store, dispatch already will call that action generator.

```
 connect(mapStateToProps, { yourActionCreator })(Component);
```

Comment: I am using redux thunk.